# How to remove delay before running code in VS Code while connected to network without internet access

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I run code in VS Code while connected to a wireless network without internet access, using either "Start Debugging" or "Run Without Debugging" from the "Run" drop down menu, there is a delay of around 60 seconds before the code is run.

As soon as I select the option to run the code, the control bar as appears, and the progress-bar in the "Run and Debug" tab starts moving. However, nothing happens until after the delay.

Control bar:

[image: Control bar]

Run and Debug progress-bar:

[image: Run and debug progress-bar]

If I manually run the code in the terminal in VS Code, using a command like,

```
python3 sample_code.py
```

the code is run immediately. Similarly, if I connect to a network with internet access, or disconnect my WiFi entirely, the code is also run immediately.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS am using VS Code version 1.58.2.

Is there a way to remove this delay?